# how to find common number from multiple file?

Tags: text-processing, awk, comm

I want to extract common number present in all file. I have 1000 file in folder. I Want to compare all file number and find out common number in 1000 file. I have used below code:

```
for ((i=2;i<=10000;i++))  
do
comm -12 --nocheck-order a.txt "$i".txt > final.txt
mv final.txt file.txt
done
```

But it is only over writting and comparing only last file with a.txt.
But I want common number present in all file.

let say a.txt file:

> 1
>   3
>   47
>   8
>   6
>   7

1.txt file :

> 2
>   3
>   6
>   7
>   8

2.txt file :

> 3
>   5
>   6
>   7
>   9

3.txt and 4.txt....1000.txt. If this works fine for this 3 file, It should work fine for all file. So common in this file is:

> 3
>   7

while it is giving me

> 3
>   8
>   3

Please let me know how I can proceed?

Comment: Where from did the file.txt come into the picture? Should it not be a.txt instead? We need to update the a.txt every iteration. Post iterstion, this file would hold the final answer.

Comment: (1) If you have 1000 (10³) files, why are you running the loop up to 10000 (10⁴)?  (2) If you have a `1.txt`, why are you starting your loop at `i=2`?  (3) If you have an `a.txt`, and also `1.txt` through `1000.txt`, then you have 1001 files, don’t you?  (4) The number “6” is present in the three files you presented (`a.txt`, `1.txt` and `2.txt`); why do you not expect it to be in your output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming each number can only appear once in a file:

```
$ awk '{c[$1]++} END{for (i in c) if (c[i] == (ARGC-1)) print i}' a.txt {1..2}.txt
3
6
7
```

Answer (score 0):

first to know that to have `comm` report common lines among multiple files correctly you will need to pass input files as sorted if they are not already sorted before.

second is you need change your `mv` command to `mv final.txt a.txt`; in order to check next file against of the result of previous attempt; here I took a backup from `a.txt` and used `common.txt` instead for iteration on it in the for-loop.

so you will have your final script as below:

```
cp a.txt common.txt
for ((i=1;i<=10000;i++));
    do comm -12  <(sort common.txt) <(sort $i.txt) >temp.txt;
    mv temp.txt common.txt;
done
```

finally `cat common.txt` will be those lines are common among 10000 files
.

Comment: You can also do the loop iteration like `for i in {1..10000}; do ...; done`

Comment: @annahri that way will fail if there was million of files when shell wants to expand; check with `printf '%s\n' {1..1000000000}
-bash: brace expansion: failed to allocate memory for 1000000000 elements` another issue with this is it's slow because it should wait shell expand the brace then it will do the loop over elements built.

Answer (score 0):

`comm` is only for sorted files, the

> Compare **sorted** files FILE1 and FILE2 line by line.

source : https://linux.die.net/man/1/comm

so the algorithm will not work for unsorted files. This works :

```
#!/bin/sh

sort -n a.txt > tmp.txt

END=4

for i in `seq 2 $END`
do
comm -12 --nocheck-order tmp.txt $i.txt |tee tmp.txt
done
cp tmp.txt "final.txt"
```

Instead of the `|tee` you can also use the `>` operator on some systems (writing to file with overwriting it)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with overwriting your output in each iteration.  The `>` redirection will *truncate* (empty) the file that you redirect into.

Another approach: Sort each file individually with `sort -u` to get the entries unique to that file, then concatenate the results of these sorting operations and pass it through `sort | uniq -c` to get the sum of the number of times each entry appears in all files.  Then go through that result and pick out the entries that have counts equal to the number of files.  These are the entries that occur in all files.

```
set -- ./*.txt

for file do
    sort -u "$file"
done | sort | uniq -c |
awk -v c="$#" '$1 == c { print $2 }'
```

I'm making use of the positional parameters here, setting them to the list of files that we'd like to iterate over with `set -- ./*.txt`.  I do this so that we can use `$#` later, which is the number of files in the list.

For the three first datasets that you show, this would output

```
3
6
7
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside other issues, your script loop is calling `comm` 10000 times making it very slow. A faster alternative is to sort all of them and count the repeats. The lines that have a count equal to the number of files exists in all files (if values inside each file are not repeated):

```
set -- ./*.txt
sort -n "$@" | uniq -c | awk -vcount="$#" '$1==count{print $2}'
```

I am using the positional arguments to both have the list of files `"$@"` and also the count of files `$#`.

The sort is numeric `-n` as you ask for a *number*.

You could **check** (and sort) that no file has repeated numbers with:

```
set -- ./*.txt

for    f; do
       sort -n "$f"          > "$f.tempfile"
       mv      "$f.tempfile"   "$f"
       if [ "$(uniq -d "$f")" != "" ]; then echo $f; fi
done
```

Which will list all the files that have repeated numbers and that will sort each individual file.